# How to set up htaccess to redirect a particular post type or subdirectory to HTTPS?

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect, htaccess, https

I have a post type with the slug 'open-tour', so all its pages are under www.domain.com/open-tour/. **I need all the pages under this "directory" to go to HTTPS (for credit card payments).**

I can redirect a single URL okay, but the dynamic stuff goes a bit over my head. Maybe it's also because I don't know how/where to write the redirect in relation to Wordpress's htaccess block.

Anyway here's the latest iteration of my fail code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.domain.com/open-tour/(.*) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/open-tour/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Thanks JMa and Pothi! Now, is there a way to make another rule that is the reverse of this? That is, if the user is viewing a page that's NOT in the open-tour directory, then redirect to HTTP? I tried the following code, but it didn't work. Is says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule !^open-tour/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/open-tour/$1 [R,L]
```

I figured it would be a simple matter of adding the exclamation point, but I guess not. Sorry I wrote this in a comment below, but it wasn't formatted very nice :P This whole thing wouldn't be an issue, but unfortunately once you get to the HTTPS page and go elsewhere on the site, the HTTPS sticks. I have a Constant Contact plugin that pulls up a warning for trying to pull unencrypted data to an encrypted https protocol.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because HTTP_HOST can only contain a hostname. To specify the path as [rewrite condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), you may use REQUEST_URI, like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/open-tour`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^open-tour/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/open-tour/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Your code would work, only if `RewriteBase /` is set. Also, it doesn't work for http://sitename.com/open-tour (without the trailing slash).

Comment: Right. I've edited code.

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Is there a way to make another rule that is the reverse of this? That is, if the user is viewing a page that's NOT in the open-tour directory, then redirect to HTTP?

I tried this, but it didn't work. Is says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^open-tour/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/open-tour/$1 [R,L]`

Answer (score 2):

To let other pages to be viewed only on HTTP, you may try this complete code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^open-tour/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/open-tour/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REWRITE_URI} !^open-tour
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that causes a redirect error :(